# UIActivityViewController social sharing (Facebook) only shows first Object in NSArray

Tags: ios, facebook, share

I am trying to share content via Facebook throug the UIActivityViewController and it is working but not showing the correct data.
I am using the following code:

```
-(void)shareContent{
Item *nItem = [_items getItem:_currentPage];
NSString * urlString = @"http://www.foo.com";
NSString *url1=nItem.img;
NSMutableString *url2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[url2 appendString:url1];
[url2 appendString:800];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url2];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

NSArray * shareItems = @[urlString, img];

UIActivityViewController * avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

But is only showing the urlString message, not the image.
Hope you can help with this.

**UPDATE - EDIT**

Is working fine in Notes, it shows both of them so I think I should something different for Facebook.

Comment: I'd guess that your image is too big.  What size is it?  Also does it work if you try and share only the image?

Comment: Yes, if I only share the image is working fine and it show it. Also see my Edit, if a Share it with notes it works fine and it shows both.